# Loading web view with proxy in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to load a URL to a web view behind a proxy. Is there any way or any package to implement this.
I am using [pywebview](https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview) to load the URL but I can't find any thing about using proxy in this package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did yoou consider exporting environmnet variables in the same shell?

```
export http_proxy=http://user:password@host:port
export https_proxy=http://user:password@host:port
```